# ionic: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my ionic.project to allow Cross Origin Request that I found after research

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/path",
      "proxyUrl": "http://www.url.com/path"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run ionic serve on my cmd terminal, it launches the browser and I get this on the console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.url.com/Token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I used this plugin to manipulate with Content-Security-Policy:

[cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

This helped me.

Comment: I have added that several times, no result

Comment: Did you add this in your index.html?
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">

Comment: And this <access origin="*"/> in you config.xml

Comment: Hope, this will help you.

Comment: This issue is not CSP it has to do with CORS.

Comment: Still have'nt found a head way

Comment: Reason: (CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). What I see in my console...